# Implementing MVP in Web Applications

Tags: php, mvp

As I understand it, MVP is a derivative of MVC where the Model and the View are loosely or completely decoupled, and the Presenter replaces the Controller and acts as the bridge between the View and the Model.  This pattern seems more appropriate than traditional MVC in web applications *(whether or not that is true is not the subject of this question, so please refrain from going down that direction)*.

**My problem is in implementing the various MVP pieces in PHP, using a passive view.** Here is my current flow of things:

1. The PHP script sets up an autoloader and a router. To me, this means whatever view was in existence send an event of some kind to the server.
2. The router then determines which presenter should be used based on the request.
3. **Here be dragons.**  The Presenter acts as the bridge between the View and the Model and should take a View and a Model as dependencies so it can easily be tested.  That means I need to know what model and view I should be using before the presenter is created.

The presenter seems to be the class that knows what Model and what View it needs, so how can I move that logic out of the presenter? I understand that the generic pattern to use is a factory, I just can't seem to understand how to implement it in this case.

Perhaps I am doing this all wrong.  Maybe I've been coding for too long of a stretch and am experiencing mind warp.  Regardless of why I can't seem to understand how to solve this problem, I'll accept any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I know what you're asking. You are right that you load the appropriate controller based on the request. That controller is typically associated with a model and a view.

Let's say you have a URL that looks like: `http://www.example.com/test/view/1`

It would be fairly standard to load the Test controller, call the method `view` pass it the argument `1`. So let's assume you have:

- TestController.php
- TestModel.php
- test.php (view)

When the TestController loads it includes the model, TestModel, where your "data stuff" goes (I think you understand that). So for this example, let's say `view` wants to load the last 5 posts from the user with id `1`. So in TestController.php:

```
function view($arg)
{
    $userID = $arg;
    $posts = $this->model->loadPosts($userID);
    $this->render('test', $posts); // outputs the HTML in test.php
}
```

And in test.php, you can loop through `$posts` and output it however you choose.

It seems like you already know how this stuff works though, which is why I am confused as to what you're asking. Does this clear up anything?

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to think of Web Apps in terms of states and state transitions. the application is in a particular state, it's "at" a View, some HTML was with the aid of the associated Presenter from data in the Model and rendered to the browser . The user takes an action and this is going to move our app to a new state. So we are moving from one View/Presenter pair to another. In my mind the Model is a longer lived, evolving thing, I don't see us getting a new Model for each transition.

So you have PresenterA, responsible for responding to events in ViewA.

PresenterA receives some event, performs some work that may result in Model changes, and then decides which View to go to, say ViewB. ViewB can create its Presenter. As per the Wikipedia example (not PHP I realize, but the principle is clear):

```
 public class DomainView: IDomainView
 {
     private IDomainPresenter domainPresenter;

     public DomainView()   // Constructor
     {
        this.domainPresenter = new ConcreteDomainPresenter(this);
     }
 }
```

In effect the Presenter is the creator of the next View/Presenter pair. If you have more complex logic replace the explicit constructor

```
 new ConcreteDomainPresenter(this);
```

with a factory, working with View and Model information.